# How to transfer Leaflet Markers Lat/Long in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

My code below will add a marker in a map and display its lat/lng in alert.

```
var note = document.getElementById('note');
var datepick = document.getElementById('demo1');
var timepick = document.getElementById('timepick');
layerpoly.on('click', function(e){
    var markerA = new L.Marker(e.latlng,{icon: Icon1});
    markerA.bindPopup("</a><br><strong>FIRE</strong></br><strong>Date:</strong>"+datepick.value+"</br><strong>Time:</strong>"+timepick.value+"</br><strong>Address:</strong>"+note.value+"<strong><br><strong>Suspect Sketch</strong><br><a href=legends/suspect.jpg rel=lightbox><img src = legends/suspect.jpg height=100 width = 100/>").addTo(map);
    closure1 (markerA)
    alert(markerA.getLatLng());
```

How can i transfer the lat/lng in two separate textbox during click event?

```
<input id="userLat" type="text" name="val-lat" value="User Latitude" />
<input id="userLng" type="text" name="val-lng" value="User Longitude" />
```

Comment: What are you asking... how to set a textbox value? How to get a textbox value? it's not clear what your specific question is

Comment: like for example sir i just want to transfer the lat/lng value of my marker in the textbox. when i place a marker in my map the marker lat/lng will show in the 2 textbox

Comment: So what is your problem? Getting the lat and long as separate values? Or assigning them to the text boxes?

Comment: yes sir get the lat and long value of my marker and transfer it in two textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`markerA.getLatLng()` returns a [Leaflet LatLng object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng). To get the numbers individually, do something like:

```
var ll = markerA.getLatLng();
alert("latitude: " + ll.lat);
alert("longitude: " + ll.lng);
```

Then assign it to the input boxes as you would with any other Javascript task:

```
var ll = markerA.getLatLng();
document.querySelector('#userLat').value = ll.lat;
document.querySelector('#userLng').value = ll.lng;
```

Comment: Why not just set the textboxes.. like the OP is asking, rather than alert them?

Comment: I am assuming assigning the value of the textbox isn't the core of the question, I'll edit my answer htough.

Comment: sir thanks for the code but how can i show it in textbox because your codes output is only alert. anyways thank you

Comment: @CaptStoneInformationTechnolo I added the sample code for populating the input boxes as well

Comment: thanks for this code i will accept this after 3 mins stackoverflow rules :D